# Setting a class variable as the output of a method in an abstract class

Tags: java

I am extending on an existing library that has an abstract class (let’s call it ‘A’) with an abstract method (let’s call it ‘A.a()’) that returns an instance of another class (‘B’). **I seek to have information on which instances of B ‘belong’ (were created by) which instances of A.** The way that I was thinking about doing this was to use the returned instance of B from A.a() as a class variable for A. The problem is that, in the library, A has already been implemented over fifty times and is called many more times than this.

Some further background on the library, the classes A and B are part of a larger recursive pattern where an instance of A contains children (other instances of A) developing a hierarchy. **The hierarchy of A is developed first then A.a() is used to develop the hierarchy of B (by creating instances of B also with children) however neither ‘know’ anything about the other which is what I am trying to change.**

Currently, I have designed a new method in A ('A.c()') that can be called at the return statement of each of the implementations of a() in the subclasses. The A.c() simply takes the instance of B that was being returned, sets a variable to that instance and then returns that instance of B to the return statement of A.a().

The classes and methods that A and B relate to in the actual library are: Atom (A), Box (B) and createBox (A.a()). A.b and A.c() I have included as they are used in my current solution (see previous paragraph).

```
public abstract class Atom {

    private Box b = null;

    public abstract Box createBox()

    protected Box setB(Box box){
        this.b = box;
        return box;
    }
}

public class Alpha extends Atom {

    ...

    public Box createBox(){
        ...
        Box box = new Box();
        ...
        return setB(box);
    }
}
```

I feel this is not a neat nor manageable solution. Ideally I’d like to just be able to write the code such that whatever A.a() returns, a variable in A is set to this. Does anyone know a way of achieving this or could perhaps suggest a broader strategy that I should look at employing to tackle the problem at a different level?

Any help particularly guidance rewording the question or requests for more info would be appreciated! I've been battling this one for a couple of days now and am sure I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

The library is jlatexmath by scilab. (http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/downloads/)

**EDIT 2**

Emboldened the purpose of the change to the library and updated the class and method names to reflect the library.

Comment: You might want to mention the library and/or provide some other context or sample code. As it is, this is almost unreadably abstract and the relationship between the classes and instances is difficult to follow.

Comment: @pvg I've added the library name, will grab a URL in a moment too. I'm struggling to think of what code samples I can add though as what I have there is literally what goes on in the library. Would you have an suggestions?

Comment: What are the specific classes and methods you're writing about and what's the overall goal of you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: That I can do :) I've mentioned what I'm trying to do a few times too but they probably get lost in the words so I'll bold them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking of classes as owning instances is very much not Java thinking, and will lead you in painful paths.

What you should be thinking about is having a factory class that produces instances and keeps track of them. That factory might want to be a singleton. You do *not* want a library to be keeping track of the objects, you want your own structure that produces *your* particular set of objects and keeps track of them however you need to keep track of them.

Comment: thanks for that! I think this is what I was looking for, structures that I should be looking to use when approaching this problem. Cheers for wading through my awfully worded question too!

Answer (score 0):

**Update: exchange a() and c()**

I would recommend to put the "tracing" code into abstract class A. This resolve the issue having already many A-sub-classes. Furthermore, I would use generics to be able to put all code you need into class A. The following is just a sketch to give an idea:

```
public abstract class A<T extends B> {
  private T b = null;

  protected abstract T a();

  public final T c() {
    this.b = a();
    return this.b;
  }
}

public class Beta extends B {
  ...
}

public class Alpha extends A<Beta> {

  ...

  protected Beta a(){
    return new Beta()
  }
}
```

So you track your relationship between A and B in the public method and use an abstract protected method to create Bs (ie, you reverse the functionality of you original methods `a()` and `c()`). This design make the implementation of `Alpha.c()` straight forward. Furthermore, using generics, it allows you to put all code into A and instantiate different B in different subclasses of A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure whether this will work though as the only method that gets called in the library is c() so I don't see how A.a() will get called at all?

Comment: I thought a() will be called by the library. Just exchange a() and c() than.

Comment: Thanks but this still leaves me in the same position of having to edit and maintain every single sub-class so I don't think it is the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Well. There is no way around this I guess. If you want to instantiate different sub-classes of B in different sub-classes of A you need to adjust all "new B()" statements. The same is true, if you use a Factory pattern as suggested by bmargulies.

Comment: Hmm fair enough. Disappointing to hear but that's ok. Thanks for the help, it was much appreciated :)